# Select all (unknown) columns based on other column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to find a sql query that will perform the following functionality. I want to be able to do this with sql instead of using c#.net arrays and processing.

Here is the table: it contains only two columns.

> conversationID | userID

I will have a list of userIDs and I want to determine what conversationIDs correspond to the list of userIDs. The conversationID will be unknown.

In other words, I want to select a unique "conversationID" column that also has rows where the userID equals all the id's in a list of IDs.

for example,
i have a list of userIDs, <1,2>
where the table may look like....

```
conversationID | userID

1 | 1

1 | 2

2 | 3

2 | 4
```

This would return "1".

Thanks

**EDIT:**
From Sebas's comment, This is a query that would get all conversationIDs for one user. Could I change this to be based on multiple rows? Perhaps with an "AND"?

> SELECT DISTINCT conversationID from table WHERE userID='1'

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate more your requirement?

Comment: `select distinct conversationid from table where userid in (...)`?

Comment: This is very close. But how do I get it based on multiple rows?

Comment: @IanMcCullough: Could provide a table like as your Output? Just like what you did with your input table.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DISTINCT` OR `GROUP BY`:

Using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversationID
FROM tbl
WHERE userID IN ('1','2')
```

Using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT conversationID
FROM tbl
WHERE userID IN ('1','2')
GROUP BY conversationID
```